# In the land of the King, there are no royalty

Tags: riddle

I live in the land of the King, though no royalty have I ever known,

Known for a great sound, and also my love of music,

Though my music is not what will keep you awake.

I can take you around the world, though I will never leave here,

And I once dominated the world's knowledge and information, though I have fallen behind lately.

I am...

**HINT 1:**

> Though I am neither doctor nor seamstress, I am renowned for my needle.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I don't think it's broad at all. I suspect that from the clues given, one should be able to come up with a good, unambiguous answer. All the answers so far (including mine) are a bit of a reach, and don't really match all of the clues.

Comment: Wow, I was sure this would be solved by now.  Added a hint. I hope it doesn't make it too obvious...

Comment: Riddles are better when they have a definite single solution (but these are also much, much harder to create) - the hint seems good though! Seems like a combination of the answers of Overlord_Mephi and zrgiu must be correct.

Comment: @JonathanAllan The answer's been found now.  I hope you find this a good riddle. :)

Comment: "In the land of the King, there are no royalty..." But there are royalcoffee.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are:

> Seattle, Washington

*I live in the land of the King, though no royalty have I ever known,*

> Seattle is in King County, and the United States lacks royalty.

*Known for a great sound, and also my love of music,*

> Seattle is next to the [Puget Sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puget_Sound) and is the birthplace of [grunge music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grunge) (a.k.a. "Seattle sound").

*Though my music is not what will keep you awake.*

> Seattle is also the home of Starbucks coffee.

*I can take you around the world, though I will never leave here,*

I've got nothing for this one.

*And I once dominated the world's knowledge and information, though I have fallen behind lately.*

> Seattle is home to numerous tech companies that used to be the latest trends.

And the hint is referring to:

> [the Space Needle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Needle).

Comment: damnit I was just writing my answer when you posted. Was going for the same answer, but couldn't figure out the "keep you awake" part. Great answer!

Comment: This is good enough that I'll give it the accepted answer.  As for the one you couldn't get, you know about Starbucks and software companies, but not [one of the biggest manufacturers of commercial aircraft in the world?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing) ;-)

Comment: "I can take you around the world, though I will never leave here": Expedia's HQ is in Bellevue, which is almost Seattle, but Boeing have moved their HQ to Chicago.

Comment: As for the "not what will keep you awake", I am also reminded of a movie title, particularly Sleepless in Seattle.

Answer (score 10):

You are

> Memphis

I live in the land of the King, though no royalty have I ever known,

> Elvis Presley (the King) lived in Graceland, located in Memphis, Tennessee

Known for a great sound, and also my love of music,

> Memphis, TN is known for its rich musical history.

Though my music is not what will keep you awake.

> Memphis BBQ can cause nightmares

I can take you around the world, though I will never leave here,

> There are Memphises all over the world, most notably in Egypt

And I once dominated the world's knowledge and information, though I have fallen behind lately.

> Windows 98 was originally developed under the code name Memphis.  Windows 98 was once the main OS in all the world, but now has fallen somewhat with the advent of iOS, Linux, etc.

Comment: Very good guess, but no.  The "sound" is something distinct from the "music"

Comment: Can you give a source that Memphis BBQ can cause nightmares or was the more of a joke?

Comment: @GordonAllocman Maybe he's confused and meant [Texas](http://www.freerepublic.com/focus/f-news/544975/posts).

Comment: More of a joke.  I actually like BBQ, but some people have sensitive stomachs and say food like that can keep them aw2ake.

Comment: This was my immediate first guess, and I didn't even know about the Windows 98 code name.  For the "keep you awake" clue I was thinking of whiskey, though too much of that would probably have the opposite effect...

Answer (score 6):

You are

> Seattle

I live in the land of the King, though no royalty have I ever known,

> Seattle is in the [King County, WA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_County,_Washington)

Known for a great sound, and also my love of music,

> Seattle borders [Puget Sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puget_Sound), and is the home of [Nirvana and Pearl Jam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_Seattle)

Though my music is not what will keep you awake.

> [People are known to stay awake there.. ?](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108160/)

I can take you around the world, though I will never leave here,

> [Festivals from all around the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seattle#Culture)

And I once dominated the world's knowledge and information, though I have fallen behind lately.

> The HQ of Microsoft is right near Seattle (Redmond)

Answer (score 4):

You are

> Space Needle/Seattle Center.

I live in the land of the King, though no royalty have I ever known,

> It is in the U.S.A. where Elvis lived.

Known for a great sound, and also my love of music,

> Has the Experience Music Project/Science Fiction Museum and Hall of Fame.
> Has the sound of people?

Though my music is not what will keep you awake.

> Has more then just music(Performing Arts, etc)

I can take you around the world, though I will never leave here,

> Multi-cultural buildings.

And I once dominated the world's knowledge and information, though I have   fallen behind lately.

> Home of the  the 1962 World's Fair.

Comment: This is the best guess so far, but not quite there yet... :D

Comment: Thanks i could not figure that out how to format it.

Comment: Had same problem when I first arrived... Welcome!

Answer (score 3):

You are:

> BBC (British Broadcasting Corporation)

Because:

> United Kingdom = "land of the king", BBC radio is known for music, BBC worldwide news is broadcast all over, but has probably fallen behind the Internet now.  There are well-known signature tunes/sounds before each main program. And I guess these services are "royalty-free"?

Comment: Good guess, but no...

Comment: Your last sentence shows good lateral thinking!

Comment: As I understand it, TV in the UK *does* require a royalty.

Answer (score 2):

Are you a:

> Record

I live in the land of the King, though no royalty have I ever known,

> There is a King Records in the US & The US never had a king

Known for a great sound, and also my love of music,

> Records can hold any type of sound, music or otherwise

Though my music is not what will keep you awake.

> Don't scratch it!!!

I can take you around the world, though I will never leave here,

> I'm having a hard time figuring this one out

And I once dominated the world's knowledge and information, though I have fallen behind lately.

> Records went down in popularity once Cassettes and CDs came out, but are still being used today

Comment: Not bad, but as I said elsewhere, the "sound" and the "music" are completely distinct things.

Answer (score 1):

The riddle is referring to

> The [Grand Ole Opry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Ole_Opry)

*I live in the land of the King, though no royalty have I ever known*

> It is located in Nashville, **Tennessee**, the same state from which [The King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_Presley) originated.  
> The U.S.A. has never had any royalty.

*Known for a great sound, and also my love of music*

> The Grand Ole Opry has been broadcasting music for close to 100 years, so it is well known and loved.

*Though my music is not what will keep you awake*

> The show lasts until late into the night, so that's what will keep you awake.

*I can take you around the world, though I will never leave here*

> The show features acts from around the world.

*And I once dominated the world's knowledge and information, though I have fallen behind lately.*

> Not entirely sure about this one...

Comment: Not the right answer, but you're on the right track.  The part about the USA having never had royalty is exactly right, and this is the closest answer so far, but no, it's not the Opry...

Answer (score 0):

You are a:

> Book

I live in the land of the King, though no royalty have I ever known,

> Fictional setting (this was just a wild guess)

Known for a great sound, and also my love of music,

> Can be music sheets or lyrics

Though my music is not what will keep you awake.

> Plot twists and other literary elements keep readers awake.

I can take you around the world, though I will never leave here,

> Helps readers imagine another place, fictional or not, but the reader stays in one spot

And I once dominated the world's knowledge and information, though I have fallen behind lately.

> Non-fiction books contained information, but the Internet and other sources have taken over

Comment: Interesting guess, but no. A book can leave the place it's at, if you take it somewhere else.

Comment: @MasonWheeler I have added more reasons to why I think it was a book.

Comment: Perhaps a particular book, like the bible?

Answer (score 0):

You are

> Stephen King

I live in the land of the King, though no royalty have I ever known,

> Lives in Maine, no King of the USA

Known for a great sound, and also my love of music,

> Is passionate about music, wrote *Pop of Kings* for Entertainment Weekly.

Though my music is not what will keep you awake.

> His scary stories will keep you awake.

I can take you around the world, though I will never leave here,

> No sure here

And I once dominated the world's knowledge and information, though I have fallen behind late

> His philanthropic projects include building libraries and encouraging literacy.

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

> CD

Reasoning:

I live in the land of the King, though no royalty have I ever known,

> Invented in USA

Known for a great sound, and also my love of music,

> it's obvious

Though my music is not what will keep you awake.

> mostly games stored on it keeps you awake

I can take you around the world, though I will never leave here,

> Movies, pictures, etc. stored on it

And I once dominated the world's knowledge and information, though I have fallen behind lately.

> It was used a lot for storing and caring a lot of information

Comment: The CD was invented in the USA, but what about the King?

Comment: It could refer to Red or Purple Book - the king's colors ;)

Comment: I have to call "citation needed" on the invented in the USA claim.